# Show HTML safely

Tags: html, text-editor

On my site, I allow users to use a rich texteditor when they submit a new ticket. Therefore, they can insert any html they way.
Till now, before I insert the ticket, I perform a check for multiple tags not being submitted (script, xml, iframe, embed and more), for security reasons ofcourse (to prevent XSS mainly).

My question, is if I have a better way to let my users use a texteditor and safely execute the html code that they sent.

Thanks, have a good day all of you!

Comment: This is not a simple task.  You should reuse existing, proven code.

Comment: Can you please refer me to such code. I've been searching for awhile with no success.

Comment: One of the canonical solutions is to use oneof the many other, more restricted, markup languages, such as BBCode, ReStructured Text, or Markdown (as here on SO), which do not allow arbitrary HTML -- if you have a rich text widget anyway, the format wouldn't matter much.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz: In what language?

Comment: @SLaks: I think you can get most anything you like in any reasonable language, but BBCode comes from the PHP crowd and RST from the Python crowd.

Comment: Also you might be interested in [Content Security Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Security_Policy) and the [new `sandbox` attribute to `iframe`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-iframe-element.html#attr-iframe-sandbox).

Comment: Probably you also want to have a look at [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com) or [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com). Markdown & other such formats are probs not an option if your audience is not tech-savvy.